# How do I interpret .rst results file with python using pyansys library?

Tags: python, ansys, pyansys

I am reading the binary files '.rst' using the ansys.mapdl library reader, and I want to understand those results. I have a beam simulated on ansys mechanical and I am evaluating total deformation, equivalent elastic strain and equivalent stress.

What nodes are associated with which values? How are all three results separated? Also, I tried printing random data just to try and make sense of it but some data are NAN, so I would like to know why that is the case.

Here is the simulation and some code
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
Here is total deformation for the first 10 nodes exported from ansys mechanical to a .txt file

```
Node Number Total Deformation (m)
1   3,4011e-002
2   3,1337e-002
3   2,8684e-002
4   2,6064e-002
5   2,3489e-002
6   2,097e-002
7   1,8522e-002
8   1,6157e-002
9   1,389e-002
10  1,1736e-002
```

Here are my results after running this small script

```
rst_results = path + "file.rst"
model = pymapdl_reader.read_binary(rst_results)
nnum, data = model.nodal_solution(0, nodes=range(1, 10))
print(data)
```

output:

```
[[-1.30837114e-03 -5.18717535e-07 -3.39862333e-02]
 [-1.19035991e-03 -6.35982671e-07 -3.13144870e-02]
 [-1.07379301e-03 -8.05693695e-07 -2.86642968e-02]
 [-9.59576794e-04 -1.01205615e-06 -2.60467228e-02]
 [-8.48646606e-04 -1.24353973e-06 -2.34735376e-02]
 [-7.41942455e-04 -1.49284317e-06 -2.09571697e-02]
 [-6.40385662e-04 -1.75494961e-06 -1.85106729e-02]
 [-5.44855004e-04 -2.02586199e-06 -1.61477097e-02]
 [-4.56160962e-04 -2.30167900e-06 -1.38825364e-02]]
```

Comment: If I calculate the Total Deformation from your first result I get:
`U = [-1.30837114e-03, -5.18717535e-07, -3.39862333e-02]`
`np.sqrt(U[0]*U[0]+U[1]*U[1]+U[2]*U[2])`
*0.03401140822181701*
Which fits nicely to the mechanical export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/pyansys/pymapdl-reader/blob/main/ansys/mapdl/reader/rst.py):

```
def principal_nodal_stress(self, rnum, nodes=None):
    """Computes the principal component stresses for each node in
    the solution.
    Parameters
    ----------
    rnum : int or list
        Cumulative result number with zero based indexing, or a
        list containing (step, substep) of the requested result.
    Returns
    -------
    nodenum : numpy.ndarray
        Node numbers of the result.
    pstress : numpy.ndarray
        Principal stresses, stress intensity, and equivalent stress.
        [sigma1, sigma2, sigma3, sint, seqv]
    Examples
    --------
    Load the principal nodal stress for the first solution.
    >>> from ansys.mapdl import reader as pymapdl_reader
    >>> rst = pymapdl_reader.read_binary('file.rst')
    >>> nnum, stress = rst.principal_nodal_stress(0)
```

So each number in your nodal number array `nnum` correspond to the stresses in `stress`.

Can you check which node numbers correspond to midside nodes? Nodal stress data for printout and postprocessing are available only for the corner nodes. So I would guess that's the reason for the `nan`.

For nodal displacements:

```
    >>> from ansys.mapdl import reader as pymapdl_reader
    >>> rst = pymapdl_reader.read_binary('file.rst')
    >>> nnum, data = rst.nodal_solution(0)
```

For elastic strain you need an element result:

```
    >>> enum, edata, enode = rst.element_solution_data(0, datatype='EEL')
    >>> enum[0]  # first element number
    >>> enode[0]  # nodes belonging to element 1
    >>> edata[0]  # data belonging to element 1
```

The available results are:

```
        EMS: misc. data
        ENF: nodal forces
        ENS: nodal stresses
        ENG: volume and energies
        EGR: nodal gradients
        EEL: elastic strains
        EPL: plastic strains
        ECR: creep strains
        ETH: thermal strains
        EUL: euler angles
        EFX: nodal fluxes
        ELF: local forces
        EMN: misc. non-sum values
        ECD: element current densities
        ENL: nodal nonlinear data
        EHC: calculated heat
        EPT: element temperatures
        ESF: element surface stresses
        EDI: diffusion strains
        ETB: ETABLE items (post1 only)
        ECT: contact data
        EXY: integration point locations
        EBA: back stresses
        ESV: state variables
        MNL: material nonlinear record
```

Comment: what does datatype='EEL' mean, if you dont mind? Also, how would I go about finding which nodes correspond to the sides? I know I would have to look within the elements at the perimeter, but how do I know programmatically what is what?

Comment: The command that selects only the corner nodes in APDL is `NSLE,s,CORNER`. In Pyansys that should be 
`ansys = launch_mapdl()`
`ansys.Nsle('S', 4)`
But I don't know if that works.

Comment: One more to go, I had posted a comment which I deleted because I might've interpreted the data wrong, but for nodal displacement, I get three values per nodes. Are those the x, y and z components? Or min, max and average deformations?

Comment: I don't find a good source for pyansys but I would assume they are  x, y and z deformations in the global coordinate system.

Comment: Interesting, it seems like ansys is saying that the last values are total deformation. I am not sure about the first two, but I can imagine they are either min or max. I will update my question with the data I am currently looking at so you can see what I mean. UPDATED